# waitpid() in process A can't catch SIGTRAP in thread created by pthread_create() in process B before B coredump

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, signals, ptrace

First, start process B (see `mt.cpp` below) , it will create a thread with `pthread_create()`. The `ppid`, `pid` and `tid` of main thread and the new thread will be outputted for process A, then both of them start a for loop and raise `SIGTRAP` , which should be caught by `waitpid()` in process A.

Second, start process A (see `attach.cpp` below) with `pid` of process B. Process A will attach to process B by `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...)`, then wait signal event using `waitpid()` in `while(true)`, call `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, ...)` if get a `SIGTRAP`, or break the loop if get a `SIGSTOP`.

Now is the problem:
Process A can catch the `SIGTRAP` raised by main thread of process B and call `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, ...)` successfully, and then process B will continue to execute as expected.

BUT!!!

When the new thread of process B raised `SIGTRAP`, process A failed to `ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, ...)` with a `errmsg` **"No such process"**, because process B has core dumped with a `errmsg` **"Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)"**.
In addition, `WIFSTOPPED(status)` turned to false and `WIFSIGNALED(status)` turned to true.

I know the default action of `SIGTRAP` is terminate the process, it seems that the `SIGTRAP` was transfered to process A after the termination action, NOT before, so process A had no chance to continue process B.

I have tried `gdb` instead of process A, both `SIGTRAP` can be caught and continued successfully. So there must be something wrong in the code of process A.

Here is `attach.cpp` executed as process A:

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
  pid_t pid = 0;
  int ret = 0;
  int status = 0;

  if (argc > 1) {
    pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("pid=%d\n", pid);
  }

  ret = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
  printf("attach ret=%d\n", ret);

  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
  ret = ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL);
  printf("cont ret=%d\n", ret);

  while (true) {
    ret = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
    printf("\nwaitpid ret=%d.\n", ret);

    int sig = 0; 
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
      printf("WIFSIGNALED\n");
      sig = WTERMSIG(status);
    } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
      printf("WIFSTOPPED\n");
      sig = WSTOPSIG(status);
    } else {
      printf("other status %d\n", status);
    }
    if (SIGTRAP == sig) {
      ret = ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, NULL);
      printf("SIGTRAP cont ret=%d err=%s\n", ret, strerror(errno));
    } else if (SIGSTOP == sig) {
      ret = ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, NULL);
      printf("SIGSTOP detach ret=%d\n", ret);
      break;
    } else {
      printf("other signal %d\n", sig);
    }
    sleep(2);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is `mt.cpp` executed as process B:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define gettid() syscall(SYS_gettid)

void *func(void * arg)
{
  printf("child ppid=%d pid=%d tid=%d\n", getppid(), getpid(), gettid());
  int i = 0;
  for (; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("child loop i=%d\n", i);
    sleep(2);
  }

  printf("\nchild before SIGTRAP\n", gettid());
  raise(SIGTRAP);
  printf("child after SIGTRAP\n\n", gettid());

  for (; i < 8; i++) {
    printf("child loop i=%d\n", i);
    sleep(2);
  }

  return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("parent ppid=%d pid=%d tid=%d\n", getppid(), getpid(), gettid());
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func, NULL);

  int i = 0;
  for (; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("parent loop i=%d\n", i);
    sleep(2);
  }

  printf("\nparent before SIGTRAP\n", gettid());
  raise(SIGTRAP);
  printf("parent after SIGTRAP\n\n", gettid());

  for (; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("parent loop i=%d\n", i);
    sleep(2);
  }

  pthread_join(tid, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Here the result:

- if you want execute the two programs by yourself, be sure that process A (attach) should be started as soon as possible after start process B.

process B:

```
$ ./mt
parent ppid=12238 pid=30389 tid=30389
parent loop i=0
child ppid=12238 pid=30389 tid=30390
child loop i=0
parent loop i=1
child loop i=1
parent loop i=2
child loop i=2

parent before SIGTRAP
child loop i=3
parent after SIGTRAP

parent loop i=3
child loop i=4
parent loop i=4

child before SIGTRAP
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

process A:

```
$ ./attach 30389
pid=30389
attach ret=0
cont ret=0

waitpid ret=30389.
WIFSTOPPED
SIGTRAP cont ret=0 err=Success

waitpid ret=30389.
WIFSIGNALED
SIGTRAP cont ret=-1 err=No such process
^C
```

Comment: I added the C flag. Although the asker says `.cpp` files, the code is straight up C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux `PTRACE_ATTACH` request, despite its argument being named *pid*,  will trace only that thread.

You can verify this by adding this function to your program and calling it in the two threads:

```
#define trprefix "TracerPid:"

int tracerpid()
{
  char stfile[100], buf[512];
  sprintf(stfile, "/proc/self/task/%d/status", (int)gettid());
  int trpid = -1;
  FILE *st = fopen(stfile, "r");
  if (st != NULL) {
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, st) != NULL) {
      if (strncmp(buf, trprefix, strlen(trprefix)) == 0)
        trpid = atoi(buf+strlen(trprefix));
    }
    fclose(st);
  }
  return trpid;
}
```

You'll see that the parent thread's Tracer PID is that of your "attach" process, while the child thread's Tracer PID is 0.

When the child thread raises `SIGTRAP`, there's no tracer for the thread, so the default action for `SIGTRAP` will be taken - the whole process will be killed. That's why your tracer says that waitpid returned `WIFSIGNALED`.

To fix this:

- In the "mt" program, move the call to `pthread_create` to be after the first delay loop, which will give you enough time to attach to the process before the new thread is created.
- Add this to the "attach" program after the `ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, ...); waitpid(...);`:

  ```
  errno = 0;
  ret = ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, NULL, PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE);
  printf("setoptions ret=%d err=%s\n", ret, strerror(errno));
  ```

  The `PTRACE_O_TRACECLONE` option will let your program trace every thread that the target creates with `clone`.
- Convert all your `waitpid(pid, ...)` to `waitpid(-1, ...)` so that your program will wait for any thread.